# JavaScript disabled - Dependant Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP .NET MVC 3 application and I am using Jquery to enhance user experience. I have a page where there is a state and county dropdown and the county dropdown is loaded based on state selected (using JQuery). Now I have certain users who have disabled JS and it is not loading.

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this (I am ready to redesign my page too if required).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible since even a change event would have to trigger backend code, which would be achieved with JS... Who/why would anyone have JS disabled!?

Comment: people concerned about security disable JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery /any javascript in your page won't work if javscript is disabled in the browser. As javascript plays a major role in improving the user experience in today's web applications,  I would definitly add a Message to the user if javascript is disabled.

```html
<noscript>
  <p>You are missing some awesome features of this site. Enable Javascript to see it</a>
</noscript>
```

If you really want to make it work without javascript, you may submit your form (the user should click on the submit button) after selecting the Country from the dropdown. Your `POST` action can read the selected country and get a list of `States` and set that in your Mode/ViewModel and send it back to the View again.  But this is not a user friendly option !. So many button clicks and Form submits. AH !!! . I would tell the user to enable javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the info Shyju. I already have the <noscript> but the user does not want to enable JS. I think my only way now is to make them hit a submit and get the counties based on the selected state. I know it is not user friendly but that is what they want.

Answer (score 1):

One potential option is to have a "JavaScript-disabled" view that allows the user to select the state, then click a submit button (where the county will be on the next view), and have the form sent to a controller that takes the state from the form, determines the counties to display, and returns a view with the possible counties (disabling the state selection on that view).

How you determine which view (the JavaScript-enhanced or JavaScript-disabled) is up to you.